# performance of perl script

Tags: perl, file, scripting

I am trying to read a dynamic record length binary file. which has data like below :

```
field1field2field3field4vector1vector2
```

now field3 defines the occurence of vectors

for ex field3 is 2, then vector1&2 would be present and if value is 3 then vector1,2&3 would be present.

I have written the below code which is working fine but giving very bad performace.

let say field1-4 is fixed and length is 2652 and each vector length is 301.
field3 is 3 bytes from position 2396.

```
my $string;
my $rep_factor;
my $size;

open (FILE, $ARGV[0]) or die $!;
my $re = 2396;
my $rec = 0;
while (<FILE>) {
   seek(FILE,$re,0);
   read(FILE,$rep_factor,2);
   my $rep_fact = undefined2defined(convert2ascii_decimal($rep_factor,0));
   $size = ($rep_fact * 301) + 2652;
   seek(FILE,$rec,0);
   read FILE,$string,$size;

   filewrite ($ARGV[1], recordparse($string));
   $rec = $size + $rec;
   $re = $size + 2396;
}
```

Please help me with the code as i am new to perl, and couldn't think of anything here.

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: If the code works as intended, but you want to improve its performance, isn't [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) the appropriate place to ask this question?

Comment: Have you seen `unpack`?

Comment: [pack](http://p3rl.org/pack) and [unpack](http://p3rl.org/unpack) are usually used to read binary formats, check the `/` template char.

Comment: i have created functiion to unpack binary strings....the performnace issue is with the reading of file

Answer (score 0):

`while (<FILE>)` reads your file into `$_` until it finds the value of the input record separator (`$/` which usually defaults to `\n`) or EOF. But then rather than working with the data in `$_` you seek back to `$re` and read it again. Finally the block ends and the loop is tested again with `<FILE>` which reads from the current position of the file handle, on until it finds the input record separator or EOF.

You can avoid all of these repeated reads if you reform the loop like this:

```
do {
   seek(FILE,$re,0);
   read(FILE,$rep_factor,2);
   my $rep_fact = undefined2defined(convert2ascii_decimal($rep_factor,0));
   $size = ($rep_fact * 301) + 2652;
   seek(FILE,$rec,0);
   read FILE,$string,$size;

   filewrite ($ARGV[1], recordparse($string));
   $rec = $size + $rec;
   $re = $size + 2396;
} until eof(FILE);
```